# some of the fields holding previous data even after clearing the data in table view cell swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

My table view contains four textfields
first TextField contains lab name
second textfield contains picker view (with options < ,> , <>, =)
  if user selects <> then we are showing two text fields other wise 
       only one

```
if selectedValue._conditionSymbol == "<>" {
            textField2.isHidden = false
        }else {
             textField2.isHidden = true
        }
```

this is initial screen 
if user click on cancel or close buttons then i need to clear the data in last two text fields.
i have used

```
textfield2.clear()
 textfield1.clear() 
tableview.reloadData
```

but it is not working [image]

after clicking cancel or close button then also getting two textfields.
but i should get pickerview data as "<" and only one texfield should be visible

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse At reuse, set to reset the cell to the initial stage. Good practice :P Anyway clearing the text will not reset the visibility :P

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
textfield2.text = ""
 textfield1.text = "" 
tableviewOutlet.reloadData
```

Comment: Thank you.yeah i have done that too. but it is not working

Comment: have you implemented inside cancel and close button method?

Comment: yeah @Shabbir Ahmad